# How to Recover HDD Formatted by "Create a Recovery Drive" Tool of Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, data-recovery, partition-recovery, testdisk

I have 2 TB USB HDD which had these drives

- F: about 1 TB with 750 GB data
- H: about 120 GB with 60 GB data
- I: about 780 GB with 250 GB data (For TV: It was raw in Windows but visible in the Smart TV)

I took 521 MB from last part of H to get new G drive. Then I run "Create a Recovery Drive" tool of Windows 8.1 and chose G drive. It said all data in the drive will be deleted. I thought it is just G drive but it deleted my whole HDD. It created 32 GB new F drive with writing 337 MB on it and rest of HDD is unallocated.

I tried these programs to get my first 3 drives but non of them helped for getting 1st partition.

- TestDisk
- MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition
- EaseUS Partition Master 9.2.2 (I deleted new F drive volume because it scans only unallocated part)
- Recuva
- PC Inspector File Recovery

Comment: @techie007 Installing Windows 7 is about 15 GB but my data is just 0.33 GB additionally I search for partition recovery firstly.

Answer (score 1):

Data recovery has no where near a 100% success rate, especially if the drive started getting used again.

If you tried all those programs, and you can't get specific info back then you're either going to have to bust out your wallet and send it to a professional recovery agency, or accept that it's been overwritten and is gone forever.

Comment: I do not think just 337 MB could overwrite all 750 GB.

Comment: Not necessarily overwrite all the space, but it can permanently overwrite the table/index that actually keeps track of the files and where they are.

Comment: Recover in the EaseUS Partition Master can see folder structure and files but it has just 1 GB limit for free.

Comment: @ide Sound promising.  So, did you buy the full version of EaseUs and give it a shot?

Comment: It is $70, I look for free solutions.

Comment: So your data isn't even worth $70?   Why are you wasting your time on it then?  Hearing that, it's not worth my time anymore.  Best of luck to ya!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Photorec will be able to recover everything it recognises that wasn't overwritten, but it won't get filenames or directory structures back. You'll also need a second drive to store all the recovered files